# How do I make a seekbar update itself after touch

Tags: android, refresh, seekbar

I hope this is a simple problem.

I have a seekbar that I want to limit the range it can be set to. This range can change depending on other factors (the values of other seekbars, etc.)

The seekbar is a simple 0 to 100 range and defines a percentage. I need this value to be a minimum which can range from 0% (normal seekbar operation) to a higher value (let's say 50% for example).

The code does its calculation and determines the minimum value depending on other variables.

When I drag the seekbar below this threshold I want it to reset its value to that minimum. Here's some sample code

```
seek6.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() { 

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {        
        int CurrentLevel = seek6.getProgress();
        if (CurrentLevel < 30) CurrentLevel = 30;
        seek6.setProgress(CurrentLevel);
            }

    return false;
    }   
     });
```

So in this sample if I drag below 30, the value will be set back up to 30.

If I drag above 30 everything is fine. If I drag below the 30 mark, then the seekbar GetValue() is coming back as 30, but the seekbar shows the lower value.

For example, if I drag it all the way down to 0 the return value is 30, but it shows 0 on screen.

How can I get the seekbar to re-display at the 30 position automatically?

I've tried to change the focus, update the seekbar from another method. Nothing has worked so far.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my answer after many gruelling hours of searching.

```
seek6.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){               
        // TODO My code goes here

        int CurrentLevel = seek6.getProgress();
        if(CurrentLevel < 30)
            CurrentLevel = 30;
        seek6.setProgress(CurrentLevel);

    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){}

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){}
});
```

Thanks to anyone who has been researching this anyway.

Comment: for anyone looking for seekbar touch control adn find a demo here https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/SeekBar-Swipecontrol

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you..

```
    final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    final SeekBar sk = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    sk.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

        int p = 0;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){
            if(p < 30){
                p = 30;
                sk.setProgress(p);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){}

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
            p = progress;
            t1.setTextSize(p);
        }
    });
```